# GridView: how to increase value of a cell by one everytime at row updating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a simple gridview.
SqlDataSource to bind tableData to gridview.

On row updating I'm trying to increase the value of a cell ( type int ) by one . 
Here is my code but is not workin g:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string str = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[8].Controls[0])).Text;
            int conv = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            int set = conv + 1;
            string conn = "conn string";
            string sqlQuery = "UPDATE TableName SET Total =@Total";
            using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dataConnection))
                {
                    dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total", set);
                    dataConnection.Open();
                    dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    dataConnection.Close();

                }
            }

        }
```

I don't know why is not working , I need to increase by one the cell of the current editing row.

Thanks

Comment: You have declared and initialized `conv` but nowhere used. What is `stra` since it's nowhere declared or initialized in your code?

Comment: And ofc my code is not working something is wrong..but I don't know where because I dont get any errors but nothing is updated

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have provided here, you are never actaully adding anything

```
int set = stra + 1;

dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total", set);
```

Try this instead

```
int stra = stra + 1;

dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total", stra);
```

Comment: Sorry take a look again at my code !...the code is not working something is wrong..but I don't know where because I dont get any errors but nothing is updated

Comment: Wrap it in a try statement, and have it catch any exceptions, just to verify 100% that nothing is going wrong http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- You're upding all rows instead of only the edited one since you haven't provided the key
- You should use [`e.NewValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) to retrieve the revised values

  ```
  string sqlQuery = "UPDATE TableName SET Total=@Total WHERE ID=@ID";
  using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection(conn))
  {
      using (SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, dataConnection))
      {
          var total = (int)e.NewValues["Total"] + 1;
          dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Total", total);
          dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", (int)e.Keys["ID"].Value);
          dataConnection.Open();
          dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
  }
  ```

  - [GridViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx)
  - [GridViewUpdateEventArgs.Keys Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.keys.aspx)

Comment: Specified cast is not valid. ( var total = (int)e.NewValues["Total"] + 1; ) I also forgot to mention that the column total is read only and it starts with 0. ( right now I haven't wrote any code for read only and the cell value is 1 ) just for testing.

Comment: And the value from the cell called Total is never edited because I'll set it read only and I need to make the increase code

Comment: So what type is `Total`? Have you debugged to see if `e.NewValues` contains `Total` at all?

Comment: Total is type int , and "value" 9 ("ID", (int)e.Keys["ID"].Value);
 ) doesn't exists . thank you I've also tried to fix but I couldn't find out how

Comment: I fixed that now I get : Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement at the like with e.Keys

Comment: now I did this : dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nr", (int)e.Keys["Nr"]).Value.ToString();and I get Specified cast is not valid.